# jquery files specifically for keyboard 'accessible mode'

Tags: jquery, accessibility

I want to include a couple of js files which are specific to an 'accessibility mode' I have setup. These files detect keyboard actions and replace a lot of the mouse functions.

Is there a good/intuative way to do this? I

Comment: Keep in mind that keyboard/mouse isn't "either/or" - and keyboard use isn't just for folks with disabilities. Many users (notably power-users, coders, etc) like to mix and match keyboard and mouse use as it suits them. Do you have a good reason for not just enabling keyboard functionality by default?

Answer (score 3):

Why wouldn't you add in accessibility by default? Special modes are similar to the seperate but equal mindset during the Civil Rights movement in the United States in the 1950-1960s. That didn't go over too well. I would simply make your event listeners listen for mouse actions and key presses.

If you are still wanting to do the seperate mode, just make a link the very first item on your page that is something like keyboard-only. A few notes:

1. If you are planning to shove it off-screen via css, make sure that you code it show on-screen with :focus. Why? People who use the keyboard only doesn't mean they use speech output. They could have a condition where they can't use a mouse.
2. Ensure the link is set via a session or cookie, because setting it per page will get annoying for users.
3. Make sure that the link appears on **every** page versus only the homepage